# When I Wrap a chips list, how can I limit the area (the wrap area) to 2 lines max?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list that I want to show in chips and organize in a Wrap widget.
However, no matter what the list.length is (or the length of a single string inside the list), I want to build only 2 lines of the Wrap area.

Here is my code:

```
class TagsView extends StatelessWidget {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> list = List<Widget>.from(
        {"bla1", "bla2", "bla3", "bla4", "bla5", "bla6", "bla7","bla8", "bla9", "bla10", "bla11", "bla12", "bla13", "bla14"}
            .map((tag) => Chip(
                  label: Text(
                    tag,
                  ),
                ))
            .toList());

    return Wrap(
      verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
      spacing: 5.0,
      runSpacing: 10.0,
      children: list,
    );
  }
}
```

and here are Examples for the unwanted code (the first screenshot is the result of the code above)

[image]

[image]

A good result will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a Container and limit the height.

It will always show the first two lines.

```
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Wrap(
        verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
        spacing: 5.0,
        runSpacing: 10.0,
        children: list,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: the problem with Container with specific height is that he depends on the screen size and can cut me a line in the middle

Comment: No it can't. The screen com have more height (pixels) but the way that flutter is made, 100 pixels will aways fit 2 lines of stack. (Unless you change paddings, font sizes and other things).

Comment: I know it's a bad solution. But in the scenario that you gave (Any number of stacks with uncontrollable text), it's not the solution that you should do, but the solution that you can do.

Answer (score -1):

Probably too late, but you can use the take method.

```
List<Widget> list = List<Widget>.from({
     "bla1",
     "bla2",
     "bla3",
     "bla4",
     "bla5",
     "bla6",
     "bla7",
     "bla8",
     "bla9",
     "bla10",
     "bla11",
     "bla12",
     "bla13",
     "bla14"
   }
       .take(2)
       .map((tag) => Chip(
             label: Text(
               tag,
             ),
           ))
       .toList());
```